# How to clean up csv where the delimeter is also within double quotes in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, command-line-interface

So I have csv that uses comma as the delimiter but it has some columns that have commas in them within double quotes that does not need to be delimiters. I need to be able to replace them with another character.

```
a,b,c,"d,blah,blah,blah",e,f

a,b,"c,blah,blah,blah",d
```

I want it to be

```
a,b,c,"d|blah|blah|blah",e,f

a,b,"c|blah|blah|blah",d
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not easy in BASH but you can do this with `grep -Eo`:

```
while read -r; do
    s=$(grep -Eo '"[^"]*"|[^,]*' <<< "$REPLY" | tr ',' '|' | tr ',' '|')
    echo $s | tr ' ' ','
done < file
```

**Output:**

```
a,b,c,"d|blah|blah|blah",e,f
a,b,"c|blah|blah|blah",d
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Hey would you mind showing me how to run the command you mentioned above in one liner assuming the input was in a file rather than a string. so like cat myfile.csv | andyourstuff

Comment: I got bash 8620 sig_send: error sending signal -34, pipe handle 0x21AC, nb 148, packsize 0, win32 error 0

Comment: That means there is some bug in the cygwin binary you're using. You can test it out on an online bash editor like `ideone.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super ugly hack, but it works.

It does one replacement at a time and checks to see if the new string is different from the old string.

```
#!/bin/bash

newstr='a,b,c,"d,blah,blah,blah",e,f'

while [ "$oldstr" != "$newstr" ]
  do
  oldstr=$newstr
  newstr=`echo $oldstr | sed 's/\([^"]*"[^,]*\)\(,\)\([^"]*".*\)/\1|\3/g'`
done

echo $newstr
```

Comment: As it stands, it seems that this will only work if you have one set of quotations per line. This will replace all commas between quotation marks.